# Error 500 (Internal Server Error) ajax and laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

Hello people I am facing a problem with my comments system in laravel and ajax. Actually it works only with php but i'm having problems with ajax.

This is the error message:

> Status Code:500 Internal Server Error. And the error says: 1/3 SQLSTATE[23000]:Integrity constraint violation:1048 Column 'post_id' cannot be null.

I am editing the comments in a modal, I can create a new comment but the problem is editing it with ajax.

JS code:

```
<script>

  var commentId = 0;
        var divcomment = null;

        $('.edit-comment').click(function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
          var divcomment = this.parentNode.parentNode;
          commentId = $("#comment-post", event.target.parentNode.parentNode).data('commentid');
          var commentBody = $(divcomment).find('#display-comment').text();
          $('#comment').val(commentBody);
          $('#edit-comment').modal();
        });

        $('#modal-save').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: urlEdit,
                data: {
                    comment: $('#comment').val(),
                    commentId: commentId,
                    _token: token,
                    _method: 'POST'
                 }
            })
            .done(function (msg){
                $(divcomment).text(msg['new_comment']);
                $('#edit-comment').modal('hide');
            });
        });

</script>
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<article class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 hidden-xs">
        <figure class="thumbnail">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="/uploads/avatars/{{ $comment->user->profilepic  }}" />
            <figcaption class="text-center">{{ $comment->user->name }}</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
        <div class="panel panel-default arrow left">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <header class="text-left">
                    <div class="comment-user"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> {{ $comment->user->name }}</div>
                    <time class="comment-date" datetime="{{ $comment->created_at->diffForHumans() }}"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> {{ $comment->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</time>
                </header>
                <div id="comment-post" data-commentid="{{ $comment->id }}">
                    <p id="display-comment">{{ $comment->comment }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel-footer list-inline comment-footer">
                @if(Auth::guest())

                    No puedes responder ningún comentario si no has ingresado.

                @else

                    @if(Auth::user() == $comment->user)
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="edit-comment" class="edit-comment">Editar</a> <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="delete-comment" class="delete-comment">Eliminar</a>
                    @endif

                    @if(Auth::user() != $comment->user)
                        <a href="#">Responder</a>
                    @endif

                @endif
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

My Edit Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit-comment" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" style="color:#000;">Editar Comentario</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="comment">Editar comentario</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="comment" id="comment"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn-comment-dismiss btn-comment-modal" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cerrar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn-comment-edit btn-comment-modal" id="modal-save"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Editar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My comments update route:

```
Route::POST('comments/', ['uses' => 'CommentsController@update', 'as' => 'comments.update']);
```

My update function on CommentsController:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        'comment' => 'required'
    ]);

    $comment = Comment::find($request['commentId']);
    if (Auth::user() != $comment->user) {
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    $comment->comment = $request['comment'];

    $comment->update();
    return response()->json(['new_comment' => $comment->comment], 200);

}
```

And finally the variables created on my Post single view "where i display the comments"

```
<script>

  var token = '{{ Session::token() }}';
  var urlEdit = '{{ url('comments/update') }}';

</script>
```

UPDATE:

Comments table scheme:

```php
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->text('comment');            
            $table->boolean('approved');
            $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('comments', function ($table){
            $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

New Update:

Errors Messages:

Error 1/3

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'post_id' cannot be null

Error 2/3

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'post_id' cannot be null

Error 3/3

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'post_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `comments` (`comment`, `approved`, `post_id`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Another yet comment, 1, , 4, 2017-06-04 04:54:34, 2017-06-04 04:54:34))

Additional Info:

**General**

```
Request URL:http://devmedia.dev/comments/update
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

**Form**

```
comment:Another yet comment
commentId:13
_token:Do1gqYfziHij1nAj2CFOWwgdt7UWuubqbawrD5uX
_method:POST
```

Whole comments routes:

```
Route::post('comments/{post_id}', ['uses' => 'CommentsController@store', 'as' => 'comments.store']);
Route::get('comments/{id}/edit', ['uses' => 'CommentsController@edit', 'as' => 'comments.edit']);
Route::POST('comments/', ['uses' => 'CommentsController@update', 'as' => 'comments.update']);
Route::delete('comments/{id}', ['uses' => 'CommentsController@destroy', 'as' => 'comments.destroy']);
Route::get('comments/{id}/delete', ['uses' => 'CommentsController@delete', 'as' => 'comments.delete']);
```

Comment: Try using `save()` instead of `update()` to update the model.

Comment: Please attach schema of comments table.

Comment: Hello @Anton look the update above in question

Comment: @JuanRincón I noticed that the address of your route is just `comments/`, while you are making a request for `comments/update`. Is this a typo, or is it possible that the wrong code is being executed?

Comment: actually the route comments/ uses CommentsController@update as comments/update. so comments/update is the route

Comment: @JuanRincón the comment you are editing, has a 'post_id'? before the update.

Comment: I did this in my models. Post model has many comments, and Comments model has many posts

Comment: I suggested `save()` instead of `update()` as `update()` usually takes a parameter; an array of fields to set to a value.  I have yet to see it used otherwise, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Daedalus already done with save and i get the same result

Comment: @JuanRincón Do you have access to your database?  Also; the error given says `1/3`, which implies there are two more errors you have not posted.  Please post them.

Comment: @JuanRincón As to the database access; since you know the comment Id; look up the comment in your database(if you have phpmyadmin access, or whatever ui you have for it(including a cli)), and check that it has a post_id value.

Comment: @Daedalus yes, every comment have a post id, in this case the only post who have comments is the post 9 "post_id = 9" about the erros 1/3 are the same, the last one "3" say the same but includes "insert into comment etc" and saying that it can't insert into post id, or can't find it "or access". Above in the question i added an update with the comments table scheme. The post id is a foreign key

Comment: @JuanRincón Dump your `$comment` variable after you create it; ensure that it has the `post_id` property.

Comment: @JuanRincón Also, please post the errors as they appear; do not try to summarize them; they may hold clues as to why this isn't working.

Comment: `code   #attributes: array:7 [▼
    "comment" => "Another yet comment"
    "approved" => true
    "post_id" => 9
    "user_id" => 4
    "updated_at" => "2017-06-04 04:32:51"
    "created_at" => "2017-06-04 04:32:51"
    "id" => 13
  ]`

Comment: @JuanRincón Please add the rest of the errors to the question, as requested.  Make sure to scrub any identifying information, such as passwords or hostnames.

Comment: @JuanRincón The stack snippet feature is for html/javascript/css code, not for general errors.  I am thus fixing it now, but please remember for the future.

Comment: Question updated, one more thing, Laravel uses the form::model to update something.. of course route is needed. And about the post_id, i did the dump on the store function, i'm able to create new comments "without JS"

Comment: @JuanRincón Okay; now I know you already answered this above, but I need to make sure we're looking at the correct code here; your Route.  Is it exactly `Route::POST('comments/'...`, or is there an `update` after the slash?

Comment: @JuanRincón I ask as error **#3** suggests that another controller method may be getting called; eg, the one to save a new comment, rather than update an existing comment, since the error points to an insert query rather than an update query.  To that end, I'd like to see the rest of your comment-related routes added to the question, please.

Comment: Is a resource controller, so originally it was `code Route::put('comments/{id}', ['uses' => 'CommentsController@update', 'as' => 'comments.update']);` but now that i'm using it with js i changed to the one posted above

Comment: @JuanRincón Please update your route(the one above) to add `update` after the slash, so it looks like this: `Route::POST('comments/update', ['uses' => 'CommentsController@update', 'as' => 'comments.update']);`.  My current hunch is the incomplete route is causing the bug.  Also, I'm not entirely sure that `POST` is meant to be in all caps, as I don't know the IoC container well enough to see how casing in facades is handled.

Comment: let me add the whole comments routes

Comment: @JuanRincón Please change your route as I noted; if I am correct I will undelete my answer.  I'd also recommend making `POST` into `post`.

Comment: @Daedalus The same.. i think i need to call the post_id maybe from the controller, look at this, this is the code i was using on "update function" before using js: `code         $comment = Comment::find($id);

        $this->validate($request, array('comment' => 'required'));

        $comment->comment = $request->comment;

        $comment->save();

        Session::flash('El comentario ha sido editado');

        return redirect()->route('posts.show', $comment->post->id);` at the end the return redirect()->route('posts.show', $comment->post->id);

Comment: @JuanRincón Well I am right; just did some testing on my end; it is conflicting routes.  Try putting your `comments.update` route above your `comments.store` route.  Of course, you could also require that your `comments.store` route's post_id parameter is an integer.

Comment: @Daedalus and now, i'm trying to edit the comments as i did before and it gives me an error: MethodNotAllowedInHttpExcepion, in other words "post method not allowed" `code at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST', 'DELETE'))`

Comment: Ok is done and is working!! but now i have a problem =P i need to refresh the page to see the comments edited.

Comment: @JuanRincón I've posted the revised answer.  Besides that point, you can see this SO answer for that question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3715123/785241

Comment: i can't make it refresh, i mean, not the whole page but the edited comment only

Comment: @JuanRincón Just change the text of your comment again, just like how you got it in the first place: `$(divcomment).find('#display-comment').text(comment)`, but in your ajax success function.

Comment: @Daedalus let me see if i got you, i will replace this on my main js file?

Comment: @JuanRincón In your `.done()` function, which is off of the ajax function, you can put the above line to update the comment.

Comment: I replaced on my .done function and works but to display the edited message i need to refresh manually the page, what i'm looking now is to load just the edited message and not the whole page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears my(and [Anton's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44350927/error-500-internal-server-error-ajax-and-laravel/44352687#comment75704256_44350927)) hunch was correct.  You have two conflicting routes.

```
Route::post('comments/{post_id}', ['uses' => 'CommentsController@store', 'as' => 'comments.store']);
```

And of course

```
Route::post('comments/', ['uses' => 'CommentsController@update', 'as' => 'comments.update']);
```

Because the two routes use roughly the same route, laravel just goes by which is defined first, which is your `comments.store` route.

There are a couple ways to fix this.

1. Change the order of your routes:

   ```
   Route::post('comments/update', ['uses' => 'CommentsController@update', 'as' => 'comments.update']);
   Route::post('comments/{post_id}', ['uses' => 'CommentsController@store', 'as' => 'comments.store']);
   Route::get('comments/{id}/edit', ['uses' => 'CommentsController@edit', 'as' => 'comments.edit']);
   ```
2. Use route constraints:

   ```
   Route::post('comments/{post_id}', [
       'uses' => 'CommentsController@store',
        'as' => 'comments.store'
   ])->where(['post_id' => '[0-9]+']);;
   Route::get('comments/{id}/edit', ['uses' => 'CommentsController@edit', 'as' => 'comments.edit']);
   Route::post('comments/update', ['uses' => 'CommentsController@update', 'as' => 'comments.update']);
   ```

Of note, I don't know how the Facade registrar handles the casing(lower, upper) of facade methods.. So in an effort to not cause further bugs, I used the lower casing of `POST`, just as it is used in the documentation.